# Sound will not default to s/pdif (DVI-to-HDMI) without unplugging headphone jack

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, dvi

I have recently installed `Lubuntu 16.04` on my HTPC and it has an `Asus M3A78-EM` motherboard and a `nVidia 9500 GT` videocard.

I have a 3.5mm audio cable running from the motherboard audio out to the TV, and a DVI-to-HDMI cable from the videocard to the TV for video.  When playing a video, no sound is emitted from the TV speakers and when using the 3.5mm cable.   The `Pulse Audio Volume Control` app to shows `Line Out (plugged in)` however (see image below) and registers sound levels but nothing makes it to the TV.  At this point there is no option for `S/PDIF` at all for me to select.

While the video is playing if I unplug the 3.5mm jack out of the back of the motherboard, sound suddenly comes through via the DVI-to-HDMI cable.  At this point the `Pulse Audio Volume Control` application shows `"Digital Output (S/PDIF)` (see image below)

How can I force Lubuntu to us the `DVI-to-HDMI` cable and use the `Digital Output (S/PDIF)` as a default when I boot the PC?

[image: 3.5mm cable plugged in after boot, no sound to TV]

[image: 3.5mm unplugged switches audio immediately after unplug]